# finish doing something (in the future)

Tags: grammar

How can I say "When you finish something, please let me know"?

> Let me know when you finish doing your work.

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Your phrasing looks okay: "When you finish doing your work, please let me know."

Comment: Do you have a specific reason you think your sentence might not be grammatically correct? Which part of the sentence are you unsure of?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you are correct there. It can also be written as:

> Let me know when your task is completed

OR

> Inform me when you accomplish your work/task.

Comment: Is it correct to say : Let me know when you have finished doing something ?

Comment: Absolutely. I just stated possible alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple rule of thumb:

You use simple present to express future time after the conjunctions *when*, *after*, *before*, *as soon as* and *until*.

So, your sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

If your uncertainty is about to finish + gerund Longman DCE has registered this construction, whereas in dictionary.com it is not mentioned.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/finish_1

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/finish?s=ts

By the way, ... when you finish your work is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

You can say it as:

> Let me know when you finish doing your work.

Or:

> When you finish doing your work, let me know.

Invoker:

> Let me know when your task is completed.

Bob The Zealot:

> When your task is completed, let me know.

Invoker:

> Inform me when you accomplish your work/task.

Bob The Zealot:

> When you accomplish your work/task, inform me.

It can go both ways, and it still mean the same thing.

Comment: 17/8                                                     You don't need that many examples. It makes the answer less dense. No one says: bob: 'HI' guy: 'HI BILL' bob 'HELLO' guy 'HELLO BILL.' It just looks weird.